# Segmentation fault after code execution (getenv.c:84 error)

Tags: c, fault

My code is simple... it just gets two sentences like `networkService(webServer, httpd,TCP, 80, apache)` and `hacl(internet, webServer, TCP, 80)`. From these two sentences the code just extracts the protocol and port from each sentence.

So for sentence: `networkService(webServer, httpd,TCP, 80, apache)` the protocol would be `TCP` and port `80`

For sentence: `hacl(internet, webServer, TCP, 80)` the protocol would be `TCP` and port `80`

That is all my code does and I get segmantation fault after the execution... that is my code below:

All this function does is to get the protocol after the first comma and the port after the third comma

```
void set_port_service(char node_name[], char protocol[], char port[]){

char* sep;
sep = node_name;

int comma_num = 0;
int i = 0; int k =0;

printf("node name: %s\n\n", node_name);

while(comma_num < 4){

    if(*sep == ',')
        comma_num++;

    sep++;

    if(comma_num == 2){

        if(*sep != ',' && *sep != ')'){

            protocol[i] = *sep;
            i++;                
        }           

    }

    if(comma_num == 3){

        if(*sep != ',' && *sep != ')'){

            port[k] = *sep;
            k++;                
        }           

    }

}

protocol[i] = 0; port[k] = 0;

remove_char(protocol); 
remove_char(port);}
```

All the function below does is to get protocol and port from the previous function and add it to vc_node->port and vc_node->protocol

```
void convert_to_dag(graph_node** dag, graph_node** sag){ //directed acyclic graph

struct Graph_Node data = { .next = NULL, .edge = NULL, .hosts = NULL, .predecessor_edge = NULL, .parent_list = NULL};

graph_node* sag_aux = *sag;

while(sag_aux != NULL){ //set vc nodes ports and services

    // service leaf node
    if(strstr(sag_aux->node_name, "networkServiceInfo") || strstr(sag_aux->node_name, "hacl")){  


        //printf("\n\nnode name: %s\n\n", sag_aux->node_name);

        graph_edge* edge_aux = sag_aux->edge;

        printf("Part 1\n\n");

        while(edge_aux != NULL){ 

            char protocol[50]; char port[50];

            memset(protocol, 0, sizeof(protocol)); memset(port, 0, sizeof(port)); 

            set_port_service(sag_aux->node_name, protocol, port); //extract port and protocol from leaf node

            graph_node* vc_node = edge_aux->node; // leaf pointing to vc node

            strcpy(vc_node->protocol, protocol); strcpy(vc_node->port, port); //copy to vc node

            edge_aux = edge_aux->next;

        }

        printf("protocol: %s ", sag_aux->edge->node->protocol); 
        printf("port: %s\n\n",sag_aux->edge->node->port);

        printf("Part 2\n\n"); 

    }

    sag_aux = sag_aux->next;

}

sag_aux = *sag;}
```

And I get a segmentation fault AFTER the code execution. It just does not make any sense... does anyone knows the cause for this?

The parte of the code which causes the segmentation fault is this one `strstr(sag_aux->node_name, "hacl")` in the `if` statement...

[CHECK CODE](https://github.com/rvmelo/intrusion-detection-system)

Comment: Run in a debugger. Catch the crash as it happens. Locate when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: I did but the  debugger shows that the segmentation fault happens in a  line of the code where there is only close brackets...  the line code the debugger shows to me has only this -> "}" so it really does not help me

Comment: Is `sag` a valid pointer? Is `*sag` a valid pointer (and note that even non-null pointers can be invalid)? Is `sag_aux->node_name` a valid pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string? When the crash happens and you caught it in the debugger, what are the values of all those? Do they look valid? Can you trace the call back up the call-stack to see that everything look okay all the way up? And please try using a memory-debugger like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you as well.

Comment: the debuggers do not help me so much but `sag`, `*sag` and `sag_aux->node_name` I think they are valid because I print `sag_aux->node_name` on every loop and all seems normal....  this is what is causing the error `strstr(sag_aux->node_name, "hacl")` inside the `if` statement but I do not know the reason why

Comment: Then `sag_aux` or `sag_aux->node_name` are probably *not* valid pointers, even if they might seem like that. If you get segmentation faults then you're most likely on a platform supported by [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), I suggest you use that to help you find memory problems. Other than that, without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's going to be hard to impossible to help you more.

Comment: ok.. I uploaded all the code just check `CHECK CODE` link at the bottom... you just need to check three files `sdn-selection.c` ,`sag.h` and `graph.h`. The project builds a graph form `AttackGraph.txt` and you can view the graph on the file `AttackGraph.eps`